# multiple alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm new to android programming and i have a question

I'm developing an alarm application that takes more than one alarm from the user to notify him later through a dialog alert.

my problem is that when the user sets for example 3 different alarms that will fires on the same day, and he left his phone for a while, and the three alarms fires one after the other, when the user picks his phone, he will only see the last notification dialog alert only, because it overrides the old two alerts where the user will not know about them which causes a problem to him.

I want the application to give multiple dialog alerts notifications. as in our case if the user have 3 different alarms and they all fires, When the user picks his phone he will see the last dialog alert but when he clicks ok the previous one will be under it and he clicks ok the first one will be under it as well to allow the user to see them all and not overriding the new alarm with the old one

is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For alarm notifications you might also want to consider using this :
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
Create a general dialog, set needed text corresponding to each alarm on it and just fire it up I don't think it will be overridden/overwritten if you create a new dialog each time. 
Here's an alram example http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/02/android-basics-alarm-service/ it also uses the `NotificationManager` to notify about alarms.

---

hope it helps abit